# Airflow | Set Variable

Tags: json, airflow

Does anyone know the syntax to update a variable from a DAG in Airflow, but in JSON format?

Right now I have this:

`Variable.set(f"update_{kwargs['table_id']}", *last_update)`

This updates the  variable  to this:

- `updated_giftcard_id  0`
- `updated_order_id    0`

But this creates new variables which is not scalable.

Ideally, I would like to update the same variable and pass them in  JSON format:

EG: `"last_ids": {"updated_giftcard_id:" "0", "updated_order_id:" "1", etc}"`

I tried passing some params like `Variable.set(key="updated_giftcard_id", value="0", serialize=True)`, but was not working properly since it was complaining that I was passing too many params.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Variable.set()` and `Variable.get()` methods do have a serialize/deserialize parameter, `serialize_json` and `deserialize_json`, respectively, to natively handle JSON-type variables.

You could extrapolate from something like this:

```py
import logging
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow.models import Variable
from datetime import datetime


@task
def variable_set():
    Variable.set(key="updated_giftcard_id", value="0", serialize_json=True)
    Variable.set(
        key="last_ids", value={"updated_giftcard_id": "0", "updated_order_id": "1"}, serialize_json=True
    )

@task
def variable_get():
    logging.info(Variable.get(key="updated_giftcard_id", deserialize_json=True))
    logging.info(Variable.get(key="last_ids", deserialize_json=True))

with DAG(
    "example",
    start_date=datetime(2021, 8, 13),
    schedule_interval=None,
    catchup=False,
) as dag:
    variable_set() >> variable_get()
```

Result from the "variable_set" task:
[image: Writing JSON variables]
Result from the "variable_get" task:
[image: Reading JSON variables]

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Last question, but will this update the entire variable or is there a way to update a specific key/value pair within the variable? EG: `update_giftcard_id: 0`, update to `1`, without changing `updated_order_id`

Comment: @CJL89 `Variable.set()` performs a delete and insert behind the scenes with the value you specify.  You'd have to update a key's value as you normally would in a dict and then pass that modified dict to the `Variable.set()` method.

Comment: I see, so from the looks of it, this might be a combination of both your answer and Jarek's below, where I grab the entire dict from the Variable, within the function update the specific key/value, and then set() the entire dict into the Variable back? Maybe I can suggest an improvement to Airflow to create a new attribute that updates key/values.

Answer (score 0):

Variables in Airflow are always strings. You can at most serialize them to string manually and deserialize when you read them back.

writing:

```
Variable.set(key="updated_giftcard_id", value=json.dumps(dictionary))
```

reading:

```
dict = json.loads(Variable.get(key="updated_giftcard_id")
```